# add a dll reference to an asp net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dll, dllimport

I have to use a third party dll in a asp net project in order to use a webservice ,i have a c# class who have to use this dll to invoque methods using this code :

```
 [DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
    private static extern string CardInfo(byte[] data);
```

first i had **DllNotFoundException** so after a long search i found that i have to put the dll in system32 or SysWOW64 so there is no more **DllNotFoundException** but the webservice is crashing with no much explanation.
what's can be wrong ?

Comment: What was used to create the DLL?

Comment: what you could do is create a dependency folder in your web application, remove the reference from the references node, then copy the .dll over to that dependency folder, then from there re-add the reference using the references->rightclick and select the one in the dependency folder then set the `CopyLocal=` property of that .Dll to `true` or you can always use / call the `Assembly.LoadFile()` method

Comment: C language was used to create the DLL

Comment: how to create a dependency folder in web application ? @MethodMan

Comment: You don't need to out it in the system directory. Don't do that. It belongs to the system.